# 検索の際に全角のスペース記号がセパレータとして扱われていない

Tags: バグ, 完了, 検索

スタック・オーバーフローやスタック・オーバーフロー・メタの検索バーで、単語のセパレータとして半角スペースではなく全角スペースを使うと正しく機能しないことに気付きました。

たとえば `python is:question` だと想定通り動作しますが、`python　is:question` だと `pythonis:question` で検索されたことになってしまい、想定通り動作しません（質問だけにフィルターされません）。

---

[image: 半角スペースだとたくさんひっかかっています]

---

[image: 全角スペースだと0 resultです]

---

I noticed that the full-width space symbol cannot be used for a word separator in the search bar on SOja and SOja Meta. This space symbol is very commonly used in Japanese. We can use it for a separator, for example, on Google. How about changing the current behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting today, we use [`Char.IsWhiteSpace()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.iswhitespace) to identify separators for search terms. This allows full-width spaces and also allows tabs, which I've heard that some programmers also use on occasion.

本日より、[`Char.IsWhiteSpace()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.iswhitespace)を使用して検索の区切り文字を識別することとします。これによって全角スペースが使用可能になりましたのでここにお知らせ致します。尚、一部のプログラマーが使うかもしれないタブも使用できるようになりました。